# PHP str_ireplace is not replacing the value in array

Tags: php

I have the below function and don't know what I'm missing to make it work:

```
private function highlight_words($items, $word) {      
    return str_ireplace($word, '<span class="highlight">'.$word.'</span>', $items);         
}
```

Where `$items` is an array and definitely contains the string `$word` and `$word` is not empty.

First I'm calling search function like this -> `$this->set('results', $this->search());` and from the `search` function -> `return $this->highlight_words($results, $search_term);`

As of [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) it should work as it's now:

> If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed with every entry of subject, and the return value is an array as well.

Comment: Do you have an example call of your function, where the `$word` is not replaced? The function itself seems ok so far.

Comment: @Morpheus please put comments like that into your question, and give us a bit more context around where you're calling those lines - is this a CakePHP app?

Comment: @scrowler thanks, added against question.

Comment: How much debugging have you done? Have you tried `$this->set('results', str_ireplace...` with dummy data and worked backwards one function at a time from there?

Comment: I think I have figured out. It looks like I use `str_ireplace` over multilevel array. Seems to be working when I am calling on a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to replace string in multidimensional array where `str_ireplace` wasn't taking any effect. Had to re-write my function a little bit to make it work:

```
private function highlight_words($items, $word) {      
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        foreach ($item as $k => $i) {           
            $items[$key][$k] = str_ireplace($word, '<span class="highlight">'.$word.'</span>', $i);                
        }
    }
    return $items;          
}
```